# How do I click a SPAN element in Internet Exlorer using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

Im trying to click on a span element on a website I accesed with Username and Password, I´ve tried all the possible ways I can imagine(most of these found on this website). Maybe you can help me out, this is the code I´m using:

```
Sub internet_explore()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim page As HTMLDocument


Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate2 "TheWebPage"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE 
DoEvents
Loop

'Here I enter code to do the login and make a search  by filling an input box and  clicking on search button

'wait for the search to load up
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Set page = ie.Document

Dim e as HTMLElementCollection
Dim c As HTMLButtonElement

For Each e In page.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If e.innerText = "10.180.9.1" Then  

      Set c = e
      c.click
      c.parentElement.click

   End If

Next

End Sub
```

This is what I search and the button I click:
[what I Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmgE6.png)

The Result I get(Table) and why I need to click on that span element since i get many results:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrQ7t.png)

```html
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-column7" style="CURSOR: pointer" unselectable="on">
<span class="Grid-Panel-All">10.180.9.1<div>
```

Comment: What actually happens when you run your code?  You might need to add a wait at certain points in your code, particularly if you're waiting for an "AJAX"-type event to complete: that would not be detected using your existing `readystate` loops.

Comment: Hi Tim,        The code runs And even finds that element, but when It clicks, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break on that line waiting a few seconds before running the click?  If that doesn't change anything then it's difficult to make any suggestions without access to the page.